# How to restore model after failed save?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We are using [ember-changeset](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset) to handle our data in forms. Data flow is usually like this: `input -> changeset -> model -> server -> model -> changeset -> input`. User change some input which is reflected in changeset and validated. When user presses `submit` changeset is baked into model which is then saved.

And here is the problem. If server refuses to accept changes then we end up with model in broken state. To overcome this we implemented custom `save` method to mimic what `model.save` does.

The basic idea is that we take the changes from the changeset and submit those to the server asi if we were just saving an model. If that fails, then basically nothing happens. The changeset stays the dirty and the underlying model is unchanged. However, when the saving succeeds, we use the data returned form the server to update the underlying entity by doing basically the same thing that the store does when saving entities normally.

This works well on both attributes and relations. The only problem is when we need to inspect relations that may have changed right after the save, sice they get updated lazily.

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*
 * Saves an object by saving changes taken from a changeset.
 * Updates the target object if the operation succeeds.
 * @param changeset the changeset to save
 * @return {Promise} a promise that resolves to an object returned by the server
 */
saveChangeset(changeset) {
  const record = changeset.get('_content'); // not entirely a public field
  const id = record.get('id');
  const constructor = record.get('constructor');
  const modelName = constructor.modelName;

  const snapshot = changesetToSnapshot(changeset);
  const operation = record.get('isNew') ? 'createRecord' : 'updateRecord';

  record._internalModel.adapterWillCommit();
  return this.adapterFor(modelName)[operation](this, constructor, snapshot)
    .then(res => {
      // propagate the changes
      const model = this.modelFor(modelName);
      const serializer = this.serializerFor(modelName);
      const payload = serializer.normalizeResponse(this, model, res, id, operation);
      if (payload.included) {
        this.push({data: payload.included});
      }
      this.didSaveRecord(record._internalModel, {data: payload.data});
      changeset.rollback();
      return res;
    });
},


/**
 * Creates s snapshot-like object based on a changeset.
 */
export default function changesetToSnapshot(changeset) {
  const model = changeset.get('_content'); // not entirely a public field
  const isNew = model.get('isNew');
  const id = model.get('id');
  const constructor = model.get('constructor');
  const modelName = constructor.modelName;

  const changes = {};
  changeset.get('changes').forEach(change => {
    changes[change.key] = null; // The value does not matter
  });

  const filterByName = fn => (name, meta) => { // eslint-disable-line func-style
    if (name in changes) {
      fn(name, meta);
    }
  };

  const fieldFilter = isNew ? fn => fn : filterByName;

  return { // emulate a snapshot
    _isChangeset: true,
    type: constructor,
    record: model,
    modelName,
    id,
    eachAttribute: fn => model.eachAttribute(fieldFilter(fn)),
    eachRelationship: fn => model.eachRelationship(fieldFilter(fn)),
    attr: key => changeset.get(key),
    belongsTo(key, options) {
      assert('Snapshot from changeset can only return the id of a belongsTo relationship, not a snapshot of it', options && options.id);
      return get(changeset, key + '.id');
    },
    hasMany(key, options) {
      assert('Snapshot from changeset can only return the ids of a hasMany relationship, not an array of snapshots', options && options.ids);
      return changeset.get(key).map(e => e.get('id'));
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: See [rollbackAttribute](https://www.emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollbackAttributes) from `DS.Model` class. This is I suppose what you are looking for.

Comment: This method sadly doesn't rollback relationships.

Comment: I have not used much relationships yet with Ember. But if you have relatively few records to update, you can create a copy of the record before saving it to store. If however the request fails you can again get the copy and save it once more in the store without making the adapter call. Also, you could alternatively try to refetch the record using [reload](https://www.emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload)

Comment: Reload would work, but is hardly ideal. Making copy is basically trying to impelment ```reloadRelations``` and that's not [easy at all](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3698)

Comment: I am currently trying to achieve this and was wondering if you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Nope, it ended up as a dead issue on github: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4974?